# Can I take a value of a changeable variable in specific moment

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm trying to display user Score in HTML. Like top 3 scores in quiz app, and i have global variable userScore that reset to 0, on each new game, and the HTML changes too. Can i take just value of userScore before new game is started, not reference to it.

example what i want:

```
userScore = 1500;    
_userScoreHTML = userScore; // 1500        

++++new game start      
userScore = 0;   
_userScoreHTML = 1500;  /// i want _userScoreHTML to stay 1500 not changed to 0;
```

```
function scoreDisplay () {
    const emptyArr = [];

    emptyArr.push(userScore); //can i use valueOf or somthing like that 

   //try to sotr empty arr so the top score = emptyArr[0]

    _scoreOne = document.getElementById("scoreOne");
    scoreOne.innerHTML = emptyArr[0];

//scoreTwo
//scoreThree


}
```

Comment: There is no pass by reference in JavaScript and there are no references with primitive values: `a = 1; b = a` will create two distinct variables and even doing `a = 2` will not change `b`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With that clear I was able to find problem. Problem is my array  inside function so array becomes empty every time fun gets called.